# How to use Cordova to check internet connection on a button click?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have installed the cordova network-information plugin, and I have the following code that validates the user on login.  I want to check the internet connection before it validates the user credentials. How to do this in ionic?

```
$scope.enterLogin = function(usern,pass)
{
   userFactory.getUser(usern).then(function(response) 
   {
     if(JSON.stringify(response.data) === "null")
     {
         alert('Please sign-up for an account.');
     }
     else
     {
         if(pass === response.data.Password)
         {
             var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
           template: '<input type="password" ng-model="userdata.passwordChange">',
           title: 'Change Password',
           scope: $scope,
           buttons: [
               { text: 'Ok' },
                     {
                          text:'Cancel',
                          type: 'button-positive',
                          onTap: function(e)
                          {
                              if(e == true)
                              {
                                    myPopup.close();
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  $location.path('/page17');
                                   console.log($location.path());
                                   myPopup.close();
                              }
                          }
                     }
                   ]
       });
         }
         else
         {
            if(pass == $scope.userdata.passwordChange)
            {
                 $location.path('/page9');
            }
            else if(pass == "omar_1992!")
            {
                 $location.path('/page9');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Login failed. Please check your credentials.');
            }

         }
     }
        });
}
```

Comment: you can use `navigator.connection.type` to get network or `navigator.online`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Network Information plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/). This will work fine in the device and also could be access to some extra information about network.

Eg.

```
 $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
```